# Upgrading spring security with cas 3.X to Cas 4.0.0

Tags: spring-security, cas

i have a problem with migrating from Cas 3.4.7 to Cas 4.0.0 , i need to change the deployerConfigContext.xml since there are lot of changes from previous version to latest version.

can any body please provide me any deployerConfigContext.xml please , i also tried but those are not working..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with 4.2.2.

Here is a sample overlay
https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template

Comment: thanks for your reply , i am trying to do upgrade based on 4.0.0 because i am not able to identify the stable release for cas ?.. , if know can u please explain about identification of stable release of version..

Comment: The current rel is 4.2.2